Using Dapper one-to-many (spliton) with generics
I am trying to map objects in a one to many relationship using Dapper. Assume a database with a Departments and a People table. People table has a DepartmentId column to create the relationship between People and Departments. Each person can only be in one department.
I have the following models in code:
public class PersonModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public DepartmentModel Department { get; set; }
}

public class DepartmentModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

I want to use Dapper to fetch People and store them in object that contains a Departments property. Which is possible with SplitOn as follows:
public Task<IEnumerable<PersonModel>> GetPeople<PersonModel>(string connectionString)
{
     using var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

     var query = "Select People.Id, People.FullName, Department.Name FROM People LEFT JOIN Departments ON People.DepartmentId = Departments.Id";

    return await connection.QueryAsync<PersonModel, DepartmentModel, PersonModel>(query, (person, department) => {
        person.Department = department;
        return person;
    }, 
    splitOn: "Id" );
}

Question: so far so good. What I want is to turn this into a re-usable method using generics and I am stuck because I cannot do the assignment person.Department = department with generics, as .Department is a property that I don't know of. And I cannot simply use department. I also tried model.typeof(TSubModel)(see below).
Is there any way to achieve this?
Code that fails is:
public Task<IEnumerable<TModel>> GetPeople<TModel, TSubModel>(string connectionString, string query)
{
     using var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

     return await connection.QueryAsync<TModel, TSubModel, TModel>(query, (model, subModel) => {
        model.subModel= subModel; // <-- obviously model.subModel fails and so does model.typeof(TSubModel). 
        return model;
    }, 
    splitOn: "Id" );
}

PS: there is a similar question that the OP answered but doesn't use SplitOn here (SO question)

Unless there was some way you could work out which property to set via reflection then this is not really possible.
You could pass through an Action<TModel, TSubModel> lambda from the outside.
But you have no way of passing query parameters or any of the other parameters that QueryAsync takes, so you should really add that in.
public Task<IEnumerable<TModel>> GetPeople<TModel, TSubModel>(string connectionString, string query, DynamicParameters? parameters, Action<TModel, TSubModel> splitOnAction)
{
    using var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    return await connection.QueryAsync<TModel, TSubModel, TModel>(query, (model, subModel) => {
        splitOnAction(model, subModel);
        return model;
    },
    parameters,
    splitOn: "Id" );
}

and
var results = await GetPeople<PersonModel, DepartmentModel>(connString, query, null,
  (person, dep) => person.Deparmtent = dep
);

But at this point I'm not sure what you gain over using Dapper directly.
I suggest you reconsider trying to do this "generically" as Dapper already provides that for you.

Many thanks for the reply. Loosing the ability to pass parameters is a dealbreaker, so I wont even test this. I suppose the first sentence is the real answer, i,e, figure it out through reflection. Wasn't able to do it myself but answer below seems legit. Will revert when I have it working.

Well you could add more parameters (see edit) but like I said you don't gain over using Dapper directly.

Works perfectly and doesn't use reflection. Thanks again. You are right in the saying that gains are marginal at best now that I am seeing it again. And code is harder to read and understand. But I asked a question and you answered it perfectly so thanks again.

If you are going to use generics, then you can use reflection to get the TModel properties, then get the TSubModel property out of it, and set its value using reflection.
Here is untested example to demonstrate the concept :
public async Task<IEnumerable<TModel>> GetPeople<TModel, TSubModel>(string connectionString, string query)
    where TModel : class
    where TSubModel : class
{
    var properties = typeof(TModel).GetProperties(); 

    var childProperty  =  properties.FirstOrDefault(s=> s.PropertyType == typeof(TSubModel));
    
    if(childProperty == null) return Enumberable.Empty<TModel>();
    
    using var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    
    return await connection.QueryAsync<TModel, TSubModel, TModel>(query, (model, subModel) => 
    {
        childProperty.SetValue(model, subModel);
        return model;
    }, 
    splitOn: "Id");
}


Upvoting this one as well, because I used it and it works. If you face a similar problem and you need to use reflection, its a good way of doing things. Just a quick note that since childProperty is set at design it should never be null (at least in theory). So if(childProperty == null) return Enumberable.Empty<TModel>(); could be removed. If you want to keep it for peace of mind then maybe handling it as an exception would be better rather than letting the application run in an unexpected manner.

just to clarify, childProperty may return null if it's not part of TModel properties list. Unless if you add more constraints that would make TModel will always have TSubModel property (say an interface for instance.). Another note that properties can be cached and reused, which would add more execution performance to the method.

i probably didn't phrase well. I meant that it should always have a TSubModel property. But even if you didn't safeguard against, this would be a bug in the code. And the application should not continue to run with an Enumearable.Empty which is misleading to the user. Other than this great answer and useful follow-up comment for caching the property. Although again for this case I would just leave it as it is, as you are only doing it once and not on every record returned from the database. So the "penalty" should be minor
